# Unable to debug in LG Optimis L7

Tags: debug, lg-optimus-l7-2

I am unable to enable debugging mode in LG Optimus L7 Dual. I am connecting the mobile to my PC and choose LG Software mode(read this in a blog that had discussion about LG Optimus). The USB Debugging option in Developer Options is greyed out. Once i unplug it, it glows and I enable it but when I connect and try to debug,my eclipse does not identify the device. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be your computer is running Windows? If so, do you have the corresponding drivers for your device installed?

Comment: No idea about the drivers and yes, my PC is running in Win 8. What would that drivers be ?

Comment: Is it ok if i install the two drivers given in http://www.lg.com/nz/support-mobile/lg-Optimus-L7-LG-P700 ?

Comment: I have no Windows (except those for light and fresh air), so I cannot check that. While there are device specific drivers, one working for multiple devices (and reportedly working well also on Win8) is Koush's [universal adb driver](http://adbdriver.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, San! I made it an answer with some additional details. As it solved your issue, please consider "accepting" it (by clicking the checkmark next to it), which indicates a solved issue when browsing question lists (and thus can serve as a light post to other users having similar problems). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your computer is running Windows, you need to install the appropriate device driver first. Most manufacturers offer one for download on their resp. websites, specifically tailored for the device in question; but that would also mean you'd need multiple drivers if you had multiple devices.

A good solution reported to work fine with multiple different devices, and also supporting Windows 8 fine, is Koushik Dutta's [universal adb driver](http://adbdriver.com/). This would hence free you from the hazzle of possible driver conflicts, if you one day decide to use a different/additional device.